# Comparing the number of duplicates in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have SQL Server 2014, 2 tables "doubles" and "export_table" with the same fields: "code", "inn". These tables contain duplicates; if the "Inn" fields match, the "code" also matches.

1. I need to take each value of the "Inn" field from the "doubles" table for which there are duplicates in this table and there are values ​​in the second table.
2. For each duplicate of the selected "Inn" value from the first table, check to see if all the "codes" ​​in the "export_table".
3. If there are none, then delete all "codes" from the "export_table" table corresponding to the codes of "doubles" table.

Below is the code what I am trying.

```
SELECT count([t1].inn) as r1,t1.inn,count([t2].inn) as r2,t2.inn  
FROM [export_table] as t1    right join  doubles as t2 on
t1.inn=t2.inn group by t1.inn,t2.inn order by r2 asc
```

[image: [1]:] "task"

Comment: Request you to provide the schema of table, sample data and expected results.

Comment: To detect duplicates you can to something like this: `... GROUP BY Inn HAVING COUNT(Inn) > 1`

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: @tobypls I know how to choose duplicates. I need to remove from 2 tables all records in which not all values are duplicate code from the first table, but there is at least one.

Comment: Then dump your results into a temp table and use the results to compare back to the tables. Something like `delete from t1 where [inn] not in (select [inn] from #tmp)`. But don't just run that statement and delete all your unrecoverable data. Think about it carefully first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this (I used temp tables, but please replace with your regular tables):

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#doubles') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #doubles
END;

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#export_table') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #export_table
END;

CREATE TABLE #doubles ([code]  varchar(100), inn varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #export_table ([code]  varchar(100), inn varchar(50))

Insert INTO #doubles([code], [inn])
values
  ('c1', 'inn1')
, ('c2', 'inn1')
, ('c3', 'inn2')
, ('c4', 'inn2')
, ('c5', 'inn3')
, ('c6', 'inn3')

Insert INTO #export_table([code], [inn])
values
  ('c1', 'inn1')
, ('c3', 'inn2')
, ('c5', 'inn3')
, ('c6', 'inn3')


 -- if you want to see what gets deleted comment line with delete and uncomment the line with select.
delete et
--select et.*
from #export_table et
join (
    select t1.inn, t1.code
      from (select code, inn, Row_number() over (PARTITION BY inn order by inn) as dup_cnt from #doubles) t1
      left join #export_table t2  on t2.inn = t1.inn and t2.code = t1.code
      where t2.code is null and t1.code is not null and t1.dup_cnt > 1
) tbl on et.inn = tbl.inn


-- Based on the description, #doubles should show original count which is 6 and #export_table shows 2 records
    select * from #doubles
    select * from #export_table
```